# PowerShell += on foreach loop is adding duplicate instances

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm using a foreach loop against an array populated by a CSV. The CSV contains lines of product names, current support status, and a version number for when support was started. Sometimes these support versions are comma separated for a variety of reasons.

When a comma-separated version is found in a row, that row is removed from the array. A new row is then created and added to the array for each version found.

The issue I'm having is that if I have a version of "7,8,9" I end up with three rows all listing version 9. Troubleshooting the script shows that the values are being split and picked up correctly, but the array seems to be updating every value with whatever the latest is. For example, the first pass would make version 7, second pass has two instances of v8, last pass ends up with v9 3 times.

How do I make the += operator not update existing rows?

```
    foreach ($line in $sheet)
    {
    if ($line.'Support Started' -cmatch ",") 
        {
        $sheet = $sheet -ne $line
        $line.'Support Started'.Split(",") |
               ForEach 
                {
                $subver = $_
                $line.'Support Started' = $subver
                $sheet = $sheet += ($line)
                }
         }
    }
```

To provide more info, if I use the following:

```
    write-host $line
    $sheet += $line
    write-host $line
```

on a file with 7,8,9 as the version, I get the following output:

Product1,Supported,7
Product1,Supported,7
Product1,Supported,8
Product1,Supported,8
Product1,Supported,9
Product1,Supported,9

When checking the value of $sheet, I get:

Product1,Supported,9
Product1,Supported,9
Product1,Supported,9

Comment: can you give an example of ur input and what do u exactly want to do?

Comment: Input is in the following format:  

`"product","status","support started"
"Product1","supported","7,8,9"`    

Then I use get-content to put that in an array, then the foreach  loop. I want the following after the loop:  

`"product","status","support started"
"Product1","supported","7"
"Product1","supported","8"
"Product1","supported","9"`  

I apologize for the formatting of this comment. I've edited about 30 times but linebreaks still aren't working.

Comment: Edit that into your post. Putting it in a comment destroys the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are not reading the file using Import-Csv?

The reason you are having problem is that when you do

```
foreach ($line in $sheet)
...
```

then the variable $line is not a copy of the line in $sheet, but a reference to the line in the sheet variable. I.e. when you change $line you are in fact changing $sheet in place.

I would try not to change $sheet while operating on the data, but instead create a new array that can hold all the data. Something like this:

```
$sheet = Import-Csv data.csv

$newsheet = @()
foreach ($line in $sheet)
{
    if ($line.'Support Started' -cmatch ",") 
    {
        $a = $line.'Support Started'.Split(",")
        ForEach ($subver in $a)
        {
            $line2 = $line.PSObject.Copy()
            $line2.'Support Started' = $subver
            $newsheet += $line2
        }
    } else {
        $newsheet += $line
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing to populate $sheet. I was not aware the data would be handled so differently. I'm still confused as to why a new line would be added and then the old lines updated, but I'm happy to have it working. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
$sheet = $sheet += ($line)
```

should read (edited)

```
$sheet += @{'product'=$line.product; 'status'=$line.status; 'support started'=$_}
```

PS gets slightly confused when $line is from $sheet, remedied by making a new object

Comment: The output is the same

Answer (score 0):

`$sheet = $sheet += ($line)`

`$sheet += $line` is already appending `$line` to `$sheet`. The extra assignment operation is probably causing your issue.

Comment: I'm still getting duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
$sheet = 
foreach ($line in $sheet)
 {
   if ($line.'Support Started' -cmatch ",") 
    {
      $line.'Support Started'.Split(",") |
           ForEach 
            {
            $subver = $_
            $line.'Support Started' = $subver
            $line
            }
     }
  else {$line}
}
```

Comment: This is still spitting the same output as before. I've done write-host $line both before and after adding the line to the sheet, and the value always writes out correctly (7, then 8, then 9), but the sheet contains duplicate rows of the last version number every time.